# how to slow down Flowslider slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have a flowslider slider, here the page of the project http://www.flowslider.com/
It's a very easy to use slider however I don't know how to reduce the sliding speed, there's no working example in the site

that's my slider initialization code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        // Select your slider element and call Flow Slider plugin.
        var $slider = $("#slider");
        $slider.FlowSlider({

            controllerOptions: [{
                mouseStart:100,
                mouseEnd:100,
            }],

            marginStart:20,
            marginEnd:20,
            mode:"horizontal"    
        });    
    });
</script>
```

the actual slider is just a

```
<div id="slider">
a bunch of PHP generated divs here, each one is a slider element
</div>
```

I tried setting `speed` and `coefficient` but without any results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the sliding speed, it's because the sliding speed depends on `user mouse action ( user mouse movement)` and `the width of content div` and `the count of images in it`. It means when you move your mouse slowly cross the slides the sliding happens slow and when you do it fast slides goe fast.
 This slide is not that kind of slides that repeats sliding in a period of time.

Comment: Ok, you misunderstood my question. The slider doesn't slide automatically, however when user moves the mouse the slider promptly moves slide elements at a given speed. I want to change that speed.

Comment: @G_G I think you didn't get the point. When the mouse is on the right edge, It should shows the last image and when it's on the left edge it should show first image. So the speed depends on two parameters; `1. Slide content div width` and `2.The count of images.`

Comment: ok I got it. But the slider takes some time to reach an element (let's say the last one), so does one can make this transition faster or slower?

Comment: [According to the document](http://www.flowslider.com/for-developers/controllers/hovercenter), yes it's possible to change the speed of reaching the elements. see `coefficient` and `moveFunction`. Set the coefficient to `0.0001` and see what happens.

Comment: @G_G If the `coefficient` option didn't work, I recommend you to use the example of `Custom Speed Function` at the bottom of the above [HoverCenter](http://www.flowslider.com/for-developers/controllers/hovercenter). The example works fine.

Comment: tried it and it worked! I had to change the controller mode from Hover to HoverCenter to enable all the option I wanted. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

As written in the documentation of `HoverCenter` you can use the `coefficient` or write your own `moveFunction`. It seems that a list for `controllerOptions` is missing in the documentation.

To get `coefficient` to work, use something like:

```
$('#flowslider').FlowSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    marginStart: 0,
    marginEnd: 0,
    controllers: ['HoverCenter'],
    controllerOptions: [{
        coefficient: 0.1
    }]
});
```